# Unusual Server behavior with sockets

Tags: c++, c, serversocket

When writing my server code I have this line:

```
newsockfd =  accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);
```

When I run the program I get no errors, but the program just freezes, and I put a print statement at the first line of the `main()` (so it should run before anything runs)
but the print statement never gets executed.

This line of code is definitely the problem because once I comment it out, my print statements work.

What might create such bizarre behavior? 
(I'm not allowed to post homework code, so unfortunately I can't post all of it)

Comment: Did you end your print statements with "`\n`" so they'd flush the output buffer before running any later code?

Comment: nope, that was actually the problem, i've acdtually heard about not including '\n', but i didn't know it caused this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this was apparently the answer, I'll write it here: If your `printf` format strings don't end with "`\n`", then they'll be buffered until either you do print a newline or your program exits. (I'm simplifying a bit.) Since your `accept` call stopped your program after that output was buffered, you couldn't see the output even though the `printf` calls were working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The other option for you is to `fflush()` the `stdout`, which will force it to "print" anything buffered regardless of the `'\n'`:

```
printf("print this now!");
fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's waiting for a connection. That's the purpose of the `accept` function.

Comment: but how can it even we waiting for a connection when that line of code isn't even execute yet? (i literally have a printf on first line of main)

Comment: That line *has* been executed. Your assessment of the flow of your code is incorrect. The `printf` has already completed, it's just written to the buffer because you haven't flushed it.

Comment: .. and which would have been revealed immediately by a single-step debugger.  Why are students being asked to write servers before they are taught how to debug?  Is the education system to totally insane?

Comment: just so you know i am extremely good at debugging, and most likely because i don't actually use a debugger. I know how to use a debugger, but it never occurred to me that it would have helped here. BTW I lied about it being hw. It's for a class that I'm going to do in a year, and I love programming so that's why I'm doing it ahead of time. I have one year of experience of programming. Last year I didn't know how to declare a variable

Comment: @BrandonLing - it never occurred to you that it would have helped here because you do not use a debugger. When trying to get complex apps/systems to work, you need evey tool available, good logging AND a good debugger :)